# SEO best practice for a breadcrumb made by a CSS drop-down menu

Tags: seo, menu, breadcrumbs

Usually I make my "breadcrumb" with a `<h1>`, at the pages top, which is perfect for the SEO, like following : `<h1>Section > Category</h1>`

But in a new project, I wish to display a drop-down menu that will be the "breadcrumb" too, like the following (see the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9MuSP/2/)**) :

```
<div class="rub">
<ul>
  <li><a href="/selected-section/">Selected section</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/other-section/">Other section</a></li>
      <li><a href="/other-section/">Other section</a></li>
      <li><a href="/other-section/">Other section</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<>
<div class="rub">
<ul>
  <li><a href="/selected-cat/">Selected category</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/other-cat/">Other cat</a></li>
      <li><a href="/other-cat/">Other cat</a></li>
      <li><a href="/other-cat/">Other cat</a></li>
      <li><a href="/other-cat/">Other cat</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

URLs will be rewrote like : `http://www.mydomain/selected-section/selected-cat/`

The Title tag will get the value : `<title>Selected section > Selected cat</title>`

**My question(s)**

How the search engines will index this navigation?

Is it a better way to declare this navigation with something like following in the menu:

```
...
  <a href="/selected-section/"><h1>Selected section</h1></a>
...
  <a href="/selected-cat/"><h2>Selected category</h2></a>
...
```

Any other idea or advice will be appreciated.

**Edit**

A solution could be the `microdata` with a `breadcrumb` type, about [breadcrumb microdata](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185417)

Please let me know if this is the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using H1's for navigation links. H1 and H2's should typically be reserved for the headings of your page.

Your on the right track using `UL`'s though, and with the breadcrumb microdata. If you use the microdata properly, Google will actually show the navigation below your pages in search results.

So to answer your question, stick with the `UL` structure for your navigation links, and yes, use the breadcrumb microdata.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think that those microdata are the best solution too. BTW I've done some `<h1>breadcrumb</h1>` (heading of pages) in a lot of websites and there is no problem with it, they are very well indexed by search engines. And as the breadcrumb gets the same contents as the title of the page, there is no need to duplicate it in a `<h1>`, don't you think so ?

Comment: By using other non relevant header tags on your page your diluting those on the actual article. You should emphasis headers when they are important. Just because you notice no change in rankings doesn't mean you haven't weakened the page. It's completely overboard to over use headers in this way and you never know if google may introduce a stuffing of header tags in this manor.

Comment: So how this breadcrumb could be considered as a `<h1>` title by google, without duplicate it ?